# VirtualBox fails to launch

Tags: virtualbox

New to Linux and askUnbuntu.  I am running 22.04 and am trying to use VirtualBox to run Kali.  I was able to download, install and create a new VM.  When I try to start the machine and before it asks me to select an ISO file, I get this error ...

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kali_VM.

Failed to load R0 module /usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0: Unable to locate imported symbol 'SUPR0FpuBegin' for module 'VMMR0.r0' (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which OS are you using for the host system? 

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 for the host

Comment: problem solved... found solution here https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=106582#

Comment: @PapaSteve - please consider posting the solution as an answer to help others - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox 6.1.34 in Ubuntu 22.04 is buggy. Use a newer version of VirtualBox (6.1.36) which you can download from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

it helped me when it stopped launching win7 VM after innocent upgrade vbox from 1.34 to 1.38.

Answer (score 1):

Helped me doing downgrade to 6.1.34, history linvx exemple:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.38-153438Ubuntufocal_amd64.deb
sudo VBoxManage extpack install --replace Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.38.vbox-extpack
sudo dpkg -r virtualbox-6.1
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.34-150636~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
sudo VBoxManage extpack install --replace Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.34.vbox-extpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems Ubuntu updatedVirtualBox to 6.1.38, so a simple `apt update` and `apt upgrade` later all worked fine again :)