# virtualbox cant start failed to open session

Tags: virtualbox

I search but cant find similar case
So here is error code for virtualbox when I start whoenix

what drive me crazy is that I instaklled already virtualbox but all was fine then I try to install android it fail just crashed

then I install some extension pack and whoenix also stopped to work

I uniinstall and install again I also purge all files but same result
anyone with some ideas??
why after reinstall I have this error ?

what it means???

---

Failed to load R0 module /usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0: Unable to locate imported symbol 'SUPR0FpuBegin' for module 'VMMR0.r0' (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:
ConsoleWrap
Interface:
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: Please give us some details. What exactly did you install, and in which order? On which platform? How did you get the error?

Comment: I install virtualbox on ubuntu 22.04 all was fine then I installed extension pack after this started problems , then I unistalled purge remove files etc I installed again and still same problem cant open session

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox fails to launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428372/virtualbox-fails-to-launch)